# Replace only if string exists in current line

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have a line such as:

```
sed -i 's/mystring/newstring/' $target
```

This command will change all `mystring` to `newstring`.

What I want now is: when the program sees `mystring`, how can I check for the current line if the string `searchstring` exists or not? If it exists, `newstring` is `1`; otherwise, `newstring` is `0`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Please describe the problem you're trying to solve, not how you think sed should solve it.

Comment: actually I meant, I have 2 patterns. For all patternA i found. I will check if patternB is exist in this line or not.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

### Solution

Assuming your input file $target contains the following:

```
some text mystring some other text
some text mystring a searchstring
just some more text
```

This command:

```
sed -i -e '/searchstring/ s/mystring/1/ ; /searchstring/! s/mystring/0/' $target
```

will change its content to:

```
some text 0 some other text
some text 1 a searchstring
just some more text
```

### Explanation

The script contains two substitute (**s**) commands separated by a semicolon.

The substitute command accepts an optional address range that select which lines the substitution should take place.

In this case *regexp* address was used to select lines containing the *searchstring* for the first command; and the lines that do not contain the *searchstring* (note the exclamation mark after the regexp negating the match) for the second one.

### Edit

This command will perform better and produce just the same result:

```
sed -i -e '/searchstring/ s/mystring/1/ ; s/mystring/0/' $target
```

The point is that commands are executed sequentially and thus if there is still a *mystring* substring in the current line *after* the first command finished then there is no *searchstring* in it for sure.

Kudos to user946850.

Comment: You were just a bit faster :-)

Comment: @user946850 Though your version performs faster. Stole it :D

Comment: Just a minor issue: A [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) looks like `#!` which I don't see in your code..

Comment: It's not necessary to use the `-e` option (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11958590/4747193) answer).

Answer (score 21):

This is from the [sed one-liners](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt) page:

> OPTIMIZING FOR SPEED: If execution speed needs to be increased (due to
>   large input files or slow processors or hard disks), substitution will
>   be executed more quickly if the "find" expression is specified before
>   giving the "s/.../.../" instruction. Thus:
>
> ```
> sed 's/foo/bar/g' filename         # standard replace command
> sed '/foo/ s/foo/bar/g' filename   # executes more quickly
> sed '/foo/ s//bar/g' filename      # shorthand sed syntax
> ```

Speed is not the issue of the question at hand, but the syntax hints help formulating the solution:

```
sed -i '/searchstring/ s/mystring/1/; s/mystring/0/' $target
```