# find index of word in file and replace previous characters with bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I got a text file. It contains multiple lines, some of the has following line:

```
[some random text till] this point , good to go
```

I need to replace `[some random text]` with `now from`

Implementation steps:

1 Find index for the phrase "this point" (mandatory, need combination of two words verify this is the right line)

2.Replace all previous characters with "now from" string

3.New line should be "now from this point , good to go"

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: We expect you to demonstrate some effort before asking others for help. If you are able to ask, surely, you are able to put those same words as search terms into a search engine. Articulating an attempt of your own helps us see where exactly you are stuck; otherwise, every answer here would have to start with "is it plugged in?"

Comment: `Find index for the phrase "this point"` Are words in a file indexed? Index is the word number in file? Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958369/replace-only-if-string-exists-in-current-line  a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is doing the job

```
sed -i -e 's|${const_prrefix}.*this:'now from'|g' ${source_file}
```

Comment: Your usage of quotes is odd here, and you violate the stated condition that you must match the two words "this point".  Perhaps you want `sed "s/${const_prefix}.*this *point/now from/g"`  Using double quotes allows you to match the value of the variable `$const_prefix` rather than the literal text `${const_prefix}`